3-Phase system Voltage conversion
If we are converting from Y to delta configuration or vice-versa, how do we convert the phases of our voltages? I've seen that we need to add or subtract 30 degrees from one another, but I don't exactly understand when I should add and when I should subtract 30° from the angle. I have also searched the internet, but couldn't find anything I could understand.

Made with microcap v12.
You can construct the "voltages" using a simulator.
Just see this. Just a difference of "30°".
R, S, T in that order ... R-S, S-T, T-R ...

